# DiscordJS Canvas attachments not being fully sent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently using Discord.js and Node for my bot that sends attachments in a set interval. I'm faced with an issue where sometimes the attachments don't fully load (they load indefinitely and only when I click "open original" can I see the top few px of the image). Why is this? Is it because the attachment file isn't complete when the attachment is sent?

**Adding Image to the File**

```js
async function makeCanvas(img, code, channel) {
  const canvas = createCanvas(900, 1375);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 1255, 900, 120);
  let image = await loadImage(img);
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, -40);
  ctx.font = "bold 100px sans-serif'";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
  ctx.fillText(`${code}`, 435, 1350);
  const writeable = fs.createWriteStream(`./temp/${channel.id}.png`);
  const readable = canvas.createPNGStream();
  const connection = readable.pipe(writeable);
  return connection.path;
}
```

**Sending the attachment**

```
const imgCode = await applyCodeToImg(url, code, message.channel);
await message.channel.send("A new attachment has appeared!", new Discord.MessageAttachment(imgCode));
```

I'm still very new to JavaScript and Node, please bear with me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
message.channel.send("message", { files: [canvas.toBuffer()] });
```

**or**

```js
const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'image.png');

message.channel.send("message", attachment);
```

to send the attachment directly, without saving it using fs, make sure to check out [Canvas#toBuffer()](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#canvastobuffer) for any futher info on the API and [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/canvas.html#basic-image-loading) on basic image loading.

Answer (score 0):

```
const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'image.png');

message.channel.send("A new attachment has appeared!", attachment);
```